# How to prevent codepipeline from deleting files in webroot?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, aws-codepipeline

I have a web app based on cakephp3. I've deployed on AWS EB using codepipeline via github. When I push commits on github, old files that have been created by the system are deleted. I mean, codepipeline replaces everything with the new files from github.
I want just to deploy the difference not everything.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I'm pretty sure AWS Codepipeline is just creating a new App Version in EB, basically a zip file of the code state, then deploying it by simply unziping the file per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html -- it then runs composer install per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-configuration-composer.html -- what exactly is the reason you don't want it to replace everything? EB servers are generally best viewed as temporary and can be deleted/replaced at any time by new instances anytime, ex. from overload